# Indexing consecutive values that sum to a target value

Tags: python, algorithm

The problem I am trying to solve is as follows: Write a function that takes an array of numbers (integers for the tests) and a target number. It should find two different items in the array that, when added together, give the target value. The indices of these items should then be returned in a tuple / list (depending on your language) like so: (index1, index2).

The faulty solution I have come up with is as follows:

```
def two_sum(numbers, target):
    list_values = [] 
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        if numbers[i-1] + numbers[i] == target:
            list_values.append(numbers.index(numbers[i-1]))
            list_values.append(numbers.index(numbers[i])) 
    return list_values
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work when the numbers[i-1] == numbers[i]. Rather than returning the two consecutive index values, it will just repeat whichever index value came first (i.e it will give [0,0] rather than [0,1]. I can't understand why it would do this: as far as I understand, the successive indexing ought not to be affected by the values of the numbers through which I'm iterating. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try using `list_values=[i-1,i]` in place of those lines with `numbers.index`.

Comment: I just ran your code and I had no problem. Maybe it had something to do with the list you used?

Comment: **1.** Index finds the first match in numbers.  Thus, `numbers[i-1] == numbers[i]` it will just return i-1.  Since the indexes are i-1 and i, you can just append them to list_values.  **2.** As a separate issue when i == 0, `numbers[i-1]` will be `numbers[-1]` which will be the last element in numbers.  Your loop should be: `for i in range(1, len(numbers))`.

Comment: Thank you everyone for all the help. This has resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`index()` will always return the index of first occurrence of the item given. hence numbers[i-1] and numbers[i] returns same index, when both of them are same numbers.
Here in this case, you dont have to search for index anyway, as you already have it as `i`.

So changing your code like below will help.

```py
def two_sum(numbers, target):
    list_values = []
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        if numbers[i-1] + numbers[i] == target:
            list_values=[i-1,i] 
    return list_values
```

Comment: Consider adding `break` statement once you have found the first match or else this will return the last match if the elements in input list are all same. Not sure what is the requirement of OP.

Comment: Yeah. thats true.

Comment: Thank you very much - I didn't realise that index worked in that way. This is clearly a much simpler solution. I would upmark this but don't have the prestige to do so ;)

Comment: Thank you Ameen - that's a useful nuance to know, though for the purpose of my problem, it wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: consider that it will consider that first and last number as consecutive.  This may or may not be what OP wants.  for example   two_sum([99,0,1],100) returns [-1,0]

Answer (score 0):

`i` and `i-1` are already your indices. If you do `numbers.index(numbers[i])`, you will just get the index of the first occurrence.

So inside your if statement:

```
list_values.append(i-1)
list_values.append(i)
```

Is this what you mean? Not completely clear to me from your description.

Do you want to return all such pairs? Or just the first one you find?

Answer (score 0):

**Efficient way** to add consecutive numbers in list and return its indices

```
def two_sum(numbers, target):
    return [(ind,ind-1) for ind, (num1, num2) in enumerate(zip(numbers, numbers[1:])) if num1+num2 == target]

print(two_sum([1,2,3,4,1,4], 5))
```

output:

```
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (3, 4)]   #[(index1, index2)]
```